# extract href values containing keyword using XPath in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, href

I know variants of this question have been asked a number of times but I've not been able to crack it and get what I want.

I have a [website](http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/ric/constantine/t.html) which has a few tables in it. The table of interest contains a column where each row contains the word `Text` hyperlinked to a different page. Here is a specific example from the first row on the above linked page:

```
<a href="_alexandria_RIC_VI_099b_K-AP.txt">Text</a>
```

This is the general pattern:

```
<a href="_something_something-blah-blah.txt">Text</a>
```

Right now I'm doing this:

```
import requests  
import lxml.html as lh
page = requests.get("http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/ric/constantine/t.html")
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
href_elements = doc.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/a/@href')
print(href_elements)
```

The desired response should be an array of items looking like this: `_something_something-blah-blah.txt` What I get is an empty array.

Since the page has other href elements I'm not interested in, I also want to modify the query to only grab the href elements that contain `.txt` in their values.

Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Comment: @mzjn, Updated per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
href_elements = doc.xpath('//center//table//a[contains(@href,".txt")]["Text"]/@href')
for href in href_elements:
    print(href)
```

Output:

```
_alexandria_RIC_VI_099b_K-AP.txt
_alexandria_RIC_VI_100.txt
_alexandria_RIC_VI_136.txt
_alexandria_RIC_VI_156.txt
```

etc.

Comment: If I am doing row-wise operations, and wanted to extract just the href tag for that row, instead of the whole table, is there a modification to the xpath command to limit the scope to that row, instead of the whole table?

Comment: @NotoriousBOG The xpath expression finds every `<a>` element in the table, if the element has an `href` attribute. If you want to limit the output to a parrticular `<a>` element, you'll have to show what is special about that element compared to all its siblings (for example, it's position in the table, a text string that's special to it, etc.) The best way to do it is to post it as a separate question with some sample html.

Comment: thanks for the response. I posted the follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453806/extract-href-on-row-by-row-basis-instead-of-the-whole-table-using-python)