# Extract href on row-by-row basis instead of the whole table using Python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, href

Here is a snipped of a table from this [website](https://www.wildwinds.com/coins/ric/constantine/i.html):

```
<table align=center border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1>

<TR><TD bgcolor="#b87333"><font size=+1><b> Alexandria</b></font><br>RIC VI 99b, K-AP</td><td>Constantine I, AE follis of Alexandria. AD 308-310. FL VAL CONSTANTINVS FIL AVG, laureate head right. / GENIO CA-ESARIS, Genius standing left, modius on head, naked but for chlamys over left shoulder, holding patera from which liquid flows, and cornucopiae. K in left field, A over P in right field. Mintmark ALE. RIC VI Alexandria 99b.</td><td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_099b_K-AP.txt">Text</A></Td><Td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_099b_K-AP.jpg">Image</A></Td></TR>

<TR><TD bgcolor="#b87333">Alexandria<br>RIC VI 100b </TD><td> Constantine, as Filius Augustorem, AE Follis. ca 308-10 AD. FL VAL CONSTANTINVS FIL AVG, laureate head right (parallel wreath ties, pointed ends) / GENIO CA-ESARIS, Genius standing left, modius on head, naked except for chlamys over left shoulder, holding patera from which liquid flows, and cornucopiae. K in left field, A over P in right field. Mintmark ALE. </td><td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_100.txt">Text</A></td><td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_100.jpg">Image</A></TD></TR>

<TR><TD bgcolor="#B87333">Alexandria<br>RIC VI 136</td><td>Constantine, AE follis. Alexandria. AD 311. 7.59g. FL VALER CONSTANTINVS PF AVG, laureate head right. / BONO GENIO PII IMPERATORIS, Genius standing front, looking left, holding patera and cornucopiae. Crescent over K in left field, A over P in right field. Mintmark ALE. RIC VI Alexandria 136.</td><TD><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_136.txt">Text</A></TD><TD><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_136.jpg">Image</A></TD></TR>

<TR><TD bgcolor="#b87333">Alexandria<br>RIC VI 156v </TD><td>Constantine AE22 Follis. 312 AD. FL VALER CONSTANTINVS PF AVG, laureate head right. / GENIO AVGVSTI, naked Genius standing left holding head of Serapis and cornucopiae, modius on head, dot/N to left, &Gamma; to right. Mintmark ALE. (dot over N not in RIC). Sear 15905v.
</td><td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_156.txt">Text</A></td><td><A HREF="_alexandria_RIC_VI_156.jpg">Image</A></TD></TR>
```

This previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876794/extract-href-values-containing-keyword-using-xpath-in-python/63906808#63906808) shows how to extract all `HREF` objects that end in .txt in the entire table.

If I already have a `for` loop that iterates over each row of that table and extracts each `TD` into a list, how could I use `XPATH` to extract the `HREF` content of the 3rd column of the table into its own list as that grows with each iteration of the `for` loop?

To be clear, I do not one to extract all `HREF` tags into one list at once (that's what the previous post did); I need to do it on a row-by-row basis so that the indexing with the other columns is maintained. In other words, how do I limit the scope of XPATH to just the row that I'm currently operating in?

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup` to parse the table?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, I suspect there's a way to do it with `beautifulsoup` but I'm not all that familiar with it and am already using `xpath` so that's why I focused the question on that implementation